# Worksheet Name in Cell / How do I write the formula so I can Call a Value in the Worksheet that's referenced in cell

Tags: excel

I'm currently having a problem with Excel.
I Tried setting the Cell Value to the Worksheet Name and making a Formula like `=A2!C2` where A2 should have the Value Q1 which is my second worksheet

[image: Image of my Excel]

Comment: The formula there references a value from C2 from a sheet named A2. You have sheets named Q1 and Q2 and have no sheet named as A2. This is why You get a #REF error.

Comment: yeah i do know that since im trying to call the sheet name Q1 wich is written in the active sheet A2. Is there some way i can make the Formula so it takes only the Value from A2 wich should be Q1 in this Case

Tyvm for quick answer

Comment: `=INDIRECT(A2&"!C2")` .... [INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261#:~:text=%20The%20INDIRECT%20function%20syntax%20has%20the%20following,is%20contained%20in%20the%20cell%20ref_text.%20More%20)

Comment: TYVM @Naresh this worked liked i wanted it

Answer (score 0):

From @Naresh =INDIRECT(A2&"!C2") .... INDIRECT function worked